# flat CSV to nested JSON tree for D3.js

Tags: json, csv, d3.js, nested, jq

I have a lot of data in a CSV that I need to convert to nested JSON to use in a D3.js tree.

Here's a sample of the CSV data:

```
Domain,Subject,Section,Topic
Networking,Networking Communications,Data Transmission,Data - Overview
Networking,Networking Communications,Data Transmission,Email
Networking,Networking Communications,Data Transmission,Datagram
Networking,Networking Communications,Networking Models,OSI Model
Networking,Networking Communications,Networking Models,TCP/IP Mode
```

This is how the JSON should look:

```
{
    "name":"Networking",
    "groups":["CS Analyst", "Cyber Crime"],
    "children":[
        {
            "name":"Networking Communications",
            "groups":["CS Analyst", "Cyber Crime"],
            "children":[
                {
                    "name":"Data Transmission",
                    "groups":["CS Analyst", "Cyber Crime"],
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "name":"Data - Overview",
                            "groups":["CS Analyst", "Cyber Crime"],
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"Email",
                            "groups":["CS Analyst", "Cyber Crime"],
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"Datagram",
                            "groups":[],
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name":"Networking Models",
                    "groups":["CS Analyst"],
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "name":"OSI Model",
                            "groups":["CS Analyst"],
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"TCP/IP Model",
                            "groups":["CS Analyst"],
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

Comment: That's not a CSV. Also, please specify the headers (1st row) precisely.

Comment: Your example data looks incomplete -- where does the `"groups":["CS Analyst", "Cyber Crime"]` information come from?

Comment: The "groups" are added by hand. I'm sorry I didn't specify that. Just trying to avoid having to manually do the rest of the JSON.

Comment: @peak my comment refers to the first version of the question, before the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) approach that supports unlimited nesting by using recursion.  Since it's unclear exactly how the `groups` value is to be computed, the following program (program.jq) uses a fixed value. If you can specify an algorithm for determining the value, it should be easy to incorporate it into the program.

The key to understanding program.jq is understanding `group_by(f)`, which groups the input array items into an array of arrays.

#### program.jq

```
def gather($supplement):
  group_by(.[0])
  | map( {name: .[0][0]} 
         + $supplement +
         {children: (if (.[0]|length) > 2
                     then (map(.[1:]) | gather($supplement))
                     else map({name:.[1]} + $supplement)
                     end) } )
  ;

split("\n") | map(split(","))
| .[1:] # skip the headers
| map(select(length>0))
| gather({"groups":["CS Analyst", "Cyber Crime"]})
| .[]
```

#### Invocation:

```
 jq -Rs -f program.jq nested.csv
```

#### Output:

```
  {
    "name": "Networking",
    "groups": [
      "CS Analyst",
      "Cyber Crime"
    ],
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Networking Communications",
        "groups": [
          "CS Analyst",
          "Cyber Crime"
        ],
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Data Transmission",
            "groups": [
              "CS Analyst",
              "Cyber Crime"
            ],
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Data - Overview",
                "groups": [
                  "CS Analyst",
                  "Cyber Crime"
                ]
              },
              {
                "name": "Email",
                "groups": [
                  "CS Analyst",
                  "Cyber Crime"
                ]
              },
              {
                "name": "Datagram",
                "groups": [
                  "CS Analyst",
                  "Cyber Crime"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Networking Models",
            "groups": [
              "CS Analyst",
              "Cyber Crime"
            ],
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "OSI Model",
                "groups": [
                  "CS Analyst",
                  "Cyber Crime"
                ]
              },
              {
                "name": "TCP/IP Mode",
                "groups": [
                  "CS Analyst",
                  "Cyber Crime"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
  "Networking, Networking Communications, Data Transmission, Data-Overview",
  "Networking, Networking Communications, Data Transmission, Email",
  "Networking, Networking Communications, Data Transmission, Something",
  "Networking,  Networking Communications,   Collection Management,   Logs",
  "Networking,  Networking Communications,   Collection Management,   Backups",
  "Networking,  Networking Communications,   Collection Management,   Configuration files",
  "Networking,  Network Architecture,    Architecture Concepts,   Types",
  "Networking,  Network Architecture,    Architecture Concepts,  Design",
  "Networking,  Network Architecture,    Network Topologies,  Comm Medias",
  "Networking,  Network Architecture,    Network Topologies,  Implementations",
  "Networking,  Network Architecture,    Intranet Extranet,  Zoning"
]

var arrayToTree = (finalArray, currentArray) => {
  var node

  currentArray.forEach((name, index) => {
    const children = index === 0 ? finalArray : node['children']
    let newNode = children.find(child => child.name === name)

    if (!newNode) {
      newNode = {
        name,
        ...(
          index < currentArray.length - 1
          ? { children: [] }
          : {}
        )
      }

      children.push(newNode)
    }

    node = newNode
  })

  return finalArray
}

var finalResult = data.map(row => row.split(/,\s+/)).reduce(arrayToTree, [])
```